# Fazer uma sequência de combinações de letras começar por uma letra específica

Tags: python

```
from string import ascii_uppercase 
import itertools 
import time

for seq in itertools.product(ascii_uppercase,repeat=3):
    sseq = ''.join(seq)
    for z in range(11111, 100000):
            passcode = ('%s%05d' % (sseq, z))
            print(passcode)
            time.sleep(0.5)
```

A saida inicial é:

```
AAA11111
AAA11112
...
```

Como posso mudar isso e fazer ele começar do:

```
FFF11111
FFF11112
```

Comment: Use os comentários para informações não técnicas.

Comment: Se uma das respostas abaixo resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, escolha a que você mais gostou e marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique a vontade para comentar. Caso ainda haja dúvidas veja [Como e porque aceitar uma resposta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/137387)

Answer (score 3):

Para começar do "F", basta... colocar o "F" no início. Mas aí não ficou claro o que você quer...

---

Você quer que comece do "F" e depois vá até o "Z", excluindo todas as combinações que tenham as letras de "A" a "E"?

Nesse caso, bastaria usar `itertools.product(ascii_uppercase[5:], repeat=3)` <-- o [*slice*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211) `[5:]` pega somente do "F" em diante (ignorando as letras de "A" e "E"). Com isso, combinações como "FAA" e "FEB" serão excluídas.

---

Ou você quer que comece do "F", mas também inclua todas as letras?

Nesse caso, bastaria rearranjar as letras, colocando o "F" no início:

```
letras = 'F' + ascii_uppercase[:5] + ascii_uppercase[6:]
for seq in itertools.product(letras, repeat=3):
    etc...
```

O *slice* `[:5]` pega as letras de "A" a "E", e `[6:]` pega tudo do "G" em diante (até o "Z"). Assim, `letras` será `FABCDEGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`: você terá todas as letras (e portanto todas as combinações possíveis), mas agora as primeiras serão "FFF11111", "FFF11112", etc.

Comment: Obrigado mano resolveu, estou com um problema de tempo agr, tenho so 2 dias pra conseguir acertar o brute force apos fazer o pedido de acesso( o acesso é so abrir um link+um passcode na url q no caso é aqueles gerados...AAA9999) mas em 2 dias o link é expirado ai tem q pedir dnv e fica nessa de expirar antes do script chegar a ZZZ...o requests é muitooo lento pra cumprir o praso q eu preciso, n preciso interagir com nada no site, so abrir a url e pronto... Sabe acelerar isso?

Comment: @iKrazy Se a resposta resolveu o seu problema, vc pode aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema. Sobre acelerar o processo, não sei, se tirar o `sleep` talvez já ajude...

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução:

```py
from string import ascii_uppercase as au
from itertools import product
import time

bl = "FFF"  # begin_letters
bn = 11111  # begin number

c = [''.join(i) for i in product(au, repeat=len(bl))]
for s in c[c.index(bl):]: 
    while bn < 100000:
        passcode = ('%s%05d' % (s, bn))
        print(passcode)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        bn += 1
    bn = 0
```

Comment: Não dá para votar e o problema não é a sua resposta, é a pergunta que não está clara. O usuário não informou se ao chegar em `ZZZ99999` deve terminar a iteração ou continuar do `AAA00000`. Talvez se você fechar cobrir esses dois caminhos consiga upvotes, pelo menos o meu consegue.

Comment: @AugustoVasques, eles estão bloqueados.

Comment: Eu escrevi errado o certo seria *...Talvez se você cobrir esses dois caminhos consiga upvotes, pelo menos o meu consegue....* . Eu estava pensando que a pergunta deveria estar fechada até o AP dar mais esclarecimentos. E qundo escrevi `Não dá para votar ` não quis dizer uma impossibilidade no sistema, eu quis dizer que a pergunta é ambígua pois possui  dois conjuntos de respostas e sua resposta cobre apenas um conjunto e não aborda o outro e o AP não dá dica de qual o caminho correto.

Comment: @AugustoVasques, Obrigado pelos esclarecimentos. Acho que AP quer obter `ZZZ99999` no final porque ele tem o código que se ajusta a ele. É um programa para força bruta e ele deseja interromper o programa a qualquer momento e reiniciá-lo, mas não do início.